# ICollection<T> Why SerializationBinder is call on HashSet<T> but not on List<T>

Tags: c#, serialization, asp.net-web-api, json.net, icollection

I have an object like this :

```
public class MyCollec
{
    public ICollection<MyObject> MyCollection { get; set; }

    public MyCollec()
    {
        MyCollection = new List<MyObject>();
    }
}
```

In WebApi i had a SerializationBinder, in my webApiConfig :

```
jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Binder = new DefaultSerializationBinder();
```

When I call my controller that return my all object i get a structure like this

```
{
  "MyCollection": [
    {
        ...
    },
    {
        ...
    }
  ]
}
```

But if i change my constructor with an hashset

```
public MyCollec()
{
    MyCollection = new HashSet<MyObject>();
}
```

The result of my controller is like this :

```
{
  "MyCollection": {
    "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[[WebApplication1.Models.MyObject, WebApplication1]], System.Core",
    "$values": [
            {
                ...
            },
            {
                ...
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I would like understand why ? What is the difference which induce this behavior ?

Is-it possible to use a HashSet but give the same result like with the list ?

EDIT :

@Grundy comment :

> TypeNameHandling property is Auto and from doc: Include the .NET type
>   name when the type of the object being serialized is not the same as
>   its declared type. So seems HashSet serialized is not the same as its
>   declared type.

It's true, it's the reason, but why it's not true for List ? The type is different of ICollection like HashSet...

Moreover, I try to change TypeNameHandling property but there no option for set $type only on inherited objects...

http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_TypeNameHandling.htm

Comment: i think default value for `TypeNameHandling` property is `Auto` and from [doc](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_TypeNameHandling.htm): _Include the .NET type name when the type of the object being serialized is not the same as its declared type._ So seems `HashSet` serialized is not the same as its declared type. :-)

Comment: why you remove your own answer? it's really solved the problem

Comment: Thanks, I believe that resolve my problem but not. because if I set TypeNameHandling to TypeNameHandling.Objects, a $type is add on all objects, I would like that $type is add only on my inherited objects...

Comment: try serialize `HashSet` directly, i not sure, but in output you can get object, instead of array, when you serialize `List` you always get array

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Grundy for the clue.

I keep

```
jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto;
```

and I had a custom JsonConverter to change the serialization of HashSet

```
public class HashSetArrayConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        IEnumerable collectionObj = (IEnumerable)value;

        writer.WriteStartObject();

        foreach (object currObj in collectionObj)
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, currObj);
        }

        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return serializer.Deserialize(reader, objectType);
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        var canConvert = IsAssignableToGenericType(objectType, typeof(HashSet<>));
        return canConvert;
    }

    private static bool IsAssignableToGenericType(Type givenType, Type genericType)
    {
        var interfaceTypes = givenType.GetInterfaces();

        if (interfaceTypes.Any(it => it.IsGenericType && it.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == genericType))
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (givenType.IsGenericType && givenType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == genericType)
            return true;

        Type baseType = givenType.BaseType;
        if (baseType == null) return false;

        return IsAssignableToGenericType(baseType, genericType);
    }
}
```

and add it in config :

```
jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new HashSetArrayConverter());
```